Problem on Heroku - "jwtSecret ('JWT_SECRET')" by overwrite "plugin-users-permissions"
To override plugin-users-permissions, I just copied the entire folder and renamed it to users-permissions for testing purposes. I haven't made any changes to anything inside it, and I can debug everything in the folder without any problems. It runs perfectly fine on my local machine.

However, when I try to deploy the project on Heroku, it throws an error:


If I add jwtSecret in the plugin.js file, it still doesn't work:


What can I do?
Originally I modified the auth.js and user.js and added a few new middlewares. When I still had Strapi v3, it worked so easily, but with Strapi v4 I would like to use these files and this structure even further.


Hello guys,
In the meantime I’ve managed a lot myself, now I just have to overwrite the two files “auth.js” and “user.js” (in “controllers”).

Can someone give me a tip?
Thanks in advance!

Hello guys,
In the meantime I’ve managed a lot myself, now I just have to overwrite the two files “auth.js” and “user.js” (in “controllers”).
Can someone give me a tip?
Thanks in advance!

I solved the problem myself by copying and adding more files from the original.
